# Regular Expression for Curly Brace

Tags: regex

I want to change the Text1 to Text2. How can i write a regular expression İf it is possible. The text contains the sub-section. The new version should be seperated with comma

Text1:

```
{Any
    {White-collar 
        {Exec-managerial} 
        {Prof-specialty} 
        {Sales} 
        {Adm-clerical}
    } 
    {Blue-collar 
        {Tech-support} 
        {Craft-repair} 
        {Machine-op-inspct} 
        {Handlers-cleaners} 
        {Transport-moving} 
        {Priv-house-serv}
    } 
    {Other 
        {Protective-serv} 
        {Armed-Forces} 
        {Farming-fishing} 
        {Other-service}
    }
}
```

Text2:

```
Exec-managerial,White-collar,Any        
Prof-specialty ,White-collar,Any        
Sales,White-collar,Any
Adm-clerical,White-collar,Any
Tech-support,Blue-collar,Any
Craft-repair,Blue-collar,Any
Machine-op-inspct,Blue-collar,Any
Handlers-cleaners,Blue-collar,Any
Transport-moving,Blue-collar,Any
Protective-serv,Other,Any
Armed-Forces,Other,Any
Farming-fishing,Other,Any
Other-service,Other,Any
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your data structure into JSON, and then use your favourite map/reduce methods to traverse it...

```
// define input text
var Text1 = `{Any
    {White-collar 
        {Exec-managerial} 
        {Prof-specialty} 
        {Sales} 
        {Adm-clerical}
    } 
    {Blue-collar 
        {Tech-support} 
        {Craft-repair} 
        {Machine-op-inspct} 
        {Handlers-cleaners} 
        {Transport-moving} 
        {Priv-house-serv}
    } 
    {Other 
        {Protective-serv} 
        {Armed-Forces} 
        {Farming-fishing} 
        {Other-service}
    }
}`

// define output array to store lines
var output = []
// parse json string into plain javascript object
JSON.parse(
    // wrap input in array
    '[' + Text1
        // replace opening braces with name/children json structure
        .replace(/{([\w-]+)/g, '{"name": "$1", "children": [')
        // replace closing braces with array close
        .replace(/}/g, ']}')
        // add commas between closing and opening braces
        .replace(/}([\n\s]*){/g, '},$1{') + ']'
// loop through outer layer
).forEach(outer => outer.children
    // inner layer
    .forEach(middle => middle.children
        // and finally join all keys with comma and push to output
        .forEach(inner => output.push([inner.name, middle.name, outer.name].join(',')))
    )
)

// join output array with newlines, and assign to Text2
var Text2 = output.join('\n')

/* Text2 =>
Exec-managerial,White-collar,Any
Prof-specialty,White-collar,Any
Sales,White-collar,Any
Adm-clerical,White-collar,Any
Tech-support,Blue-collar,Any
Craft-repair,Blue-collar,Any
Machine-op-inspct,Blue-collar,Any
Handlers-cleaners,Blue-collar,Any
Transport-moving,Blue-collar,Any
Priv-house-serv,Blue-collar,Any
Protective-serv,Other,Any
Armed-Forces,Other,Any
Farming-fishing,Other,Any
Other-service,Other,Any
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the inner braced stuff you want to leave, this should do it.

Find `(?s)(?:.*?({[^{}]*})|.*)`
Replace `$1\r\n`

```
 (?s)
 (?:
      .*? 
      ( { [^{}]* } )                # (1)
   |  
      .* 
 )
```

Otherwise, you can't get the nesting info without a complex recursive regex.

Or, use a language with a simple function recursion. You would recurse the function

In the function body, take appropriate action based on the regex  `\s*{([^\s{}]+)\s*|\s*{([^{}]+)}\s*|\s*}\s*`

```
   \s* {
   ( [^\s{}]+ )                  # (1)
   \s* 
|  
   \s* 
   {
   ( [^{}]+ )                    # (2)
   }
   \s* 
|  
   \s* } \s*
```

If $1 is not empty, push it onto an array, then call the same function (recursion).

If $2 is not empty, create a temp string, append all the items in the array,
get the next match.

If both $1 and $2 are empty, remove the last item added to the array,
then do a return from the function.

That's all there is to it.
(pseudo-code)

```
function recurse( string_thats_left )  
{
    while ( match( string_thats_left, regex ) )
    {  
        if ( $1 matched )
        {    
           push $1 onto array  
           recurse( match position to end of string );
        }
        else
        if ( $2 matched )  
        {
            write $2 to output
            for ( sizeof array )  
               append "," + element to output  
        }
        else
        {
           pop the last array element
           return
        }
    }
}
```

There is actually more to it than this, like matches must be sequential
with no breaks, but this gives the idea.